Why as $|z| \rightarrow 1^{-}$, the function $k_z$ weakly converges to 0 in $L_a^2\left(d A_\alpha\right)$？
Could you help me verity it the tollowing reasoning is correct? In the book "Operator Theory in Function Spaces" by Kehe Zhu (page 166), I am trying to show that as $|z| \rightarrow 1^{-}$, the function $k_z$ weakly converges to 0 in $L_a^2\left(d A_\alpha\right)$. The kernel $k_z$ is defined as:
$$
k_z=\frac{\left(1-|z|^2\right)^{(2+\alpha) / 2}}{|1-z \bar{w}|^{2+\alpha}} .
$$
I have reached the following inequality:
$$
\left|\left\langle k_z, g\right\rangle\right| \leq \int_{\mathbb{D}}\left|\frac{g(w)}{(1-z \bar{w})^{2+\alpha}}\right| d A_\alpha(w) \leq \frac{1}{\left(1-|z|^2\right)^{2+\alpha}} \int_{\mathbb{D}}|g(w)| d A_\alpha(w)
$$
However, I'm unsure of how to proceed from this step. Could you guide me further?

What is $L^2_a(d A_\alpha)$? What measure are you using?

@Mogget Thanks for your review.  $L^a_2 $space is Bergman space which follows $\int_{\Omega}|f(z)|^2 d A(z)<\infty$.  The measure is infinite Borel measure .
